# How to create a right JSON class in Kotlin (for Fuel)

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I have a request that returns JSON:

```
{
  "success": 0,
  "errors": {
    "phone": [
      "Incorrect phone number"
    ]
  }
}
```

I plugged Fuel instead of Retrofit for Kotlin. So, my classes are:

```
data class RegistrationResponse(
    val success: Int,
    val errors: RegistrationErrorsResponse?) {

    class Deserializer : ResponseDeserializable<RegistrationResponse> {
        override fun deserialize(content: String): RegistrationResponse? =
            Gson().fromJson(content, RegistrationResponse::class.java)
    }
}

data class RegistrationErrorsResponse(val phone: List<String>?) {

    class Deserializer : ResponseDeserializable<RegistrationErrorsResponse> {
        override fun deserialize(content: String): RegistrationErrorsResponse? =
            Gson().fromJson(content, RegistrationErrorsResponse::class.java)
    }
}
```

A request looks like:

```
class Api {

    init {
        FuelManager.instance.basePath = SERVER_URL
    }

    fun registration(name: String, phone: String): Request =
        "/registration/"
            .httpPost(listOf("name" to name, "phone" to phone))
}

private fun register(name: String, phone: String) {
    Api().registration(name, phone)
        .responseObject(RegistrationResponse.Deserializer()) { _, response, result ->
            val registrationResponse = result.component1()
            if (registrationResponse?.success == 1) {
                showScreen()
            } else {
                showErrorDialog(registrationResponse?.errors?.phone?.firstOrNull())
            }
        }
}
```

A problem is that when error occurs, `phone` variable in data class (registrationResponse?.errors?.phone) is filled with `null`, but not "Incorrect phone number".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching through Fuel issues I understood that in most cases we don't need to write own deserializators as they are already written by `Gson`.

In https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel/issues/265 there is an example. So, just put your data class inside `<>`:

```
URL.httpPost(listOf("name" to name, "phone" to phone)).responseObject<RegistrationResponse> ...
```

and get data through

```
result.component1()?.errors?.phone?.firstOrNull()
```

**Old version of answer**

Probably an obstacle is a list **deserialization**, see
1. https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel/issues/233 and
2. https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel/pull/236.

I think, by default Fuel doesn't use Gson deserialization.

I still don't know how to **deserialize** a list, But got values with this **expression**:

```
((result.component1().obj()["errors"] as JSONObject).get("phone") as JSONArray)[0]
```